# Collision detection simple snake game

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

Together with a friend of mine we are creating a multiplayer snake game. We are both beginners with JavaScript, so it is a real challenge for us. 
So far I've managed to create this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbmluijten/RG76t/3/

This is the collision detection code I have so far:

```
    Snake.prototype.collision = function (x, y, array) {
         for(var i = 0; i < Snake.length; i++){
            if(Snake.pieces[0].x == x && Snake.pieces[0].y == y)
            return true;
    }   
    return false;
   };
```

The problem I have is the collision with the snake itself.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Note that I am looking for collision with the snake itself not with the borders since we are going to put a loop into that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - you are not checking for collision at all!

The working collision: http://jsfiddle.net/RG76t/10/

Explanation:

At first you need to put the collision method in the game loop function.

```
// line 32
if (game.snakes.length !== 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < game.snakes.length; i++) {
        var s = game.snakes[i];
        s.paint(ctx, game);

        // Check for collision.
        if (s.collision()) {
            // Do something, if the collision happens.
            alert('collision');
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the collision method check if the first piece collides with any other. The loop starts from the 4th piece, since the snake's head can't really touch it's "neck" (2nd and 3rd pieces).

```
Snake.prototype.collision = function () {
    // Loop the snake pieces from the 4th one.
    for(var i = 3; i < this.length; i++){
        // Check if this piece collides with the first piece.
        if(
            this.pieces[0].x === this.pieces[i].x &&
            this.pieces[0].y === this.pieces[i].y
        ) {
            return true; // collision
        }
    }   
    return false;
};
```

Also notice that `Snake.length` and `Snake.pieces[i]` are changed to `this.length` and `this.pieces[i]`. The keyword `this` refers to the instance of a Snake on which you invoke the collision method. When you were using `Snake` in this piece of code, you were checking the properties of a constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped out a lot! Do you maybe have any idea how to create a collision script that allows me and my friend to check collision between two differed snaked? Its going to be a multiplayer snake game with node.js and every user gets an individual snake that can collide with itself and also with other users. It's hard to test but maybe you can help us out a little bit.

Comment: Still thanks a lot for you help! I see what I did wrong! It really helped a lot :D

Comment: Since you are storing snakes in game.snakes object you could check the snake's "head's" x/y coordinates with other snakes' pieces, looping the game.snakes[i].pieces. This is the easiest but not the most performance friendly solution. Though, I suppose the performance isn't the issue with the snake game. ;)

Comment: That was something me and my friend also thought about. But the problem for us is to implement this into a code. Can you maybe show us how to the code for this works? Maybe I'm asking to much from you I'm sorry about this. It would really help us! The collision between our own snake works and we are really happy with that! Thank you very much :D